# Appium: How to execute multiple test cases one after the other?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

After running this,

1. App run.
2. TestMethod1() executed.
3. App closed.
4. TestMethod2() executed.

But I don't want the app to be closed (Step3). I want **TestMethod2() to be executed after TestMethod1()** is done:

1. App run.
2. TestMethod1() execute.
3. TestMethod2() execute.
4. App close.

--> I also tried with *AddAdditionalCapability(**"NoReset, true"**)* and *AddAdditionalCapability(**"FullReset, False"**)*, which didn't work.

=> I am using **Appium.WebDriver(4.3.1)** and **C#**.

```
[TestClass]
public class Walkthrough
{
    private string _appPath = @"PathToMyApp\MyApp.apk";
    private AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> _driver;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        
        var appiumOption = new AppiumOptions();
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, _appPath);
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Pixel 4");
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "12");
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Udid, "99171FFAZ000GE");
        appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NoReset, true);

        _driver= new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), appiumOption);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        _driver.CloseApp();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() 
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.ID("ELEMENT1")).Click();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.ID("ELEMENT2")).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add priority to each test case and it will execute based on priorities. 1 is highest

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by adding **[ClassInitialize]** and **TestContext** in Setup method.
Make sure your method is **"Static"**.

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Setup(TestContext testContext)
    {
        {        
            var appiumOption = new AppiumOptions();
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, _appPath);
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Pixel 4");
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "12");
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Udid, "99171FFAZ000GE");
            appiumOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NoReset, true);

            _driver= new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), appiumOption);
        }
    }
```